# Gradle Test report is giving incorrect duration in Test Summary

Tags: java, gradle, testing, automated-tests, junit5

Can someone help me with fixing duration of Test Summary for gradle test report. When I run tests, the gradle report gives incorrect test duration information. In console, I can see that gradle test task took 1m 35s(the correct execution time), but the report says 13min 26 seconds.
P.S I am running tests in parallel mode using gradle test --parallel command
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since your build failed, you cannot be sure the report was generated. You could be looking at a stale report of a previous run.